# Excel Spreadsheet for Accounting

Tags: excel, function

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to be able to look at a PO that is typed in and query a different worksheet. The issue is that there are multiple lines with the same PO, but with different "Projected" values. The function I currently have: 
=IF(MATCH(P7,'PO REPORT - IPCIN1'!A2:A623,0)*MATCH(J7,'PO REPORT - IPCIN1'!H2:H623,0),VLOOKUP($P7,'PO REPORT - IPCIN1'!A2:I623,9,FALSE))

This only works for the first PO listed. I need to be able to somehow save the row number and return the "Amount Received" for a simple calculation within the first table.

[Worksheet for the invoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zx81.jpg)[Worksheet that is queried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH5w1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up concatenating the PO with the Projected value. I then created an extra column in the second sheet called "Lookup" with a concatenation of the projected value and the PO.
**Note: In order for my search to work, I had to create the "Lookup" column to LEFT of the column that I was looking to get returned.**
This is what the working formula looked like:
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(P9,J9),'PO REPORT - IPCIN1'!G2:J623,4,FALSE)